# Unity Events with Arguments

Tags: unity, c#

I'm fairly new to Unity and I can't really get my head around the best way to communicate between scripts.  For example, if the character jumps, what is the best way to inform other scripts (such as ground objects) to act on the characters velocity and move.

I recently had a look at [this](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/events-creating-simple-messaging-system) which describes how to make a messaging system.  My problem with this, is that I'm not sure how to pass arguments when triggering events.

For example, If I wanted to do:

```
if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")){
    EventManager.TriggerEvent("Jump", jumpVelocity);
}

...

EventManager.StartListening("Jump", OnJump);

void OnJump(velocity)
{
    //scroll ground objects horizontally
}
```

How could I add arguments to a messaging system, or would there be a better way?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Typed UnityEvent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent_1.html)

**EventManager.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Assets.Scripts
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class Event : UnityEvent<System.Object> { }

    public class EventManager : MonoBehaviour
    {

        public static EventManager Instance;

        private Dictionary<string, Event> _eventDictionary;

        private void Awake()
        {
            if (Instance == null)
            {
                Instance = this;
                _eventDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Event>();
            }
            else if (Instance != this)
                Destroy(gameObject);

            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }

        public static void StartListening(string eventName, UnityAction<System.Object> listener)
        {
            Event thisEvent = null;
            if (Instance._eventDictionary.TryGetValue(eventName, out thisEvent))
            {
                thisEvent.AddListener(listener);
            }
            else
            {
                thisEvent = new Event();
                thisEvent.AddListener(listener);
                Instance._eventDictionary.Add(eventName, thisEvent);
            }
        }

        public static void StopListening(string eventName, UnityAction<System.Object> listener)
        {
            if (Instance == null) return;
            Event thisEvent = null;
            if (Instance._eventDictionary.TryGetValue(eventName, out thisEvent))
            {
                thisEvent.RemoveListener(listener);
            }
        }

        public static void TriggerEvent(string eventName, System.Object arg=null)
        {
            Event thisEvent = null;
            if (Instance._eventDictionary.TryGetValue(eventName, out thisEvent))
            {
                thisEvent.Invoke(arg);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jer42, and welcome to GameDev.StackExchange! To keep a clear separation between questions and answers, I snipped out the question at the bottom of this post. Please consider asking that as a new question, using the "Ask Question" button at the top right. You can include a link to the answer you're asking about for context. That way folks can post answers in response to your question, you can use the Accepted flag to mark a working solution, and you can all get votes for quality contributions. :)

Comment: Ok I undersand but my question is exactly the same. I would have liked to comment on his answer to say "I do not understand, do you have an example?" but I did not have enough reputation points. Do I have the right to do this?

Comment: @Jer42 In addition to DMGregory's tip, consider this: you already received 2 upvotes for this answer. You need 3 more upvotes to be able to [comment everywhere](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/privileges). I suggest you find a couple more questions you feel able to give quality answers, and to come back here and ask Philipp directly when you get 50 rep. He's a regular user so he'll see your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the type `UnityAction` in your event handling system as suggested by that tutorial, use (or create) a different [delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms173171.aspx) type which takes an `Object` as an argument.

Add a second parameter of type `Object` to `EventManager.TriggerInvoke` and pass that parameter when you invoke the delegate.

Your event listener then receives that object you passed and is responsible for casting it to the type expected by it.

---

But note that there are many more ways to communicate between scripts than building your own subscriber-based event system.

For example, if you have a reference to another gameObject, you can use [`GetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) to get a script-based (or any other) component on it and directly call that component's methods. There are also methods for getting components from relatives in your scene hierarchy, like [`GetComponentsInChildren`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponentsInChildren.html) or [`GetComponentInParent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponentInParent.html) which can be quite useful.

And if you want to communicate between components on the same game object in a message-based manner, then you can use the method [`BroadcastMessage`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.BroadcastMessage.html) to call a method of a given name in all other components which have one.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, I assume the best way to go about it is to simply attach the camera to the character that jumps instead of moving all the surroundings individually.