# Unity: How to use delegates with EventManager ? and use variable number of arguments in listenners?

Tags: unity, events, delegates

As answered [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/137852/109778), I would like to know how to implement an [EventManager](https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/events-creating-simple-messaging-system) with delegate instead of UnityAction for pass arguments. I tried but I did not succeed.

Also, can someone tell me if it's a better solution than following ? And is it possible to change this code for invoke listenners with a variable number of arguments?

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Assets.Scripts
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class Event : UnityEvent<System.Object> { }

    public class EventManager : MonoBehaviour
    {

        public static EventManager Instance;

        private Dictionary<string, Event> _eventDictionary;

        private void Awake()
        {
            ...
        }

        public static void StartListening(string eventName, UnityAction<System.Object> listener)
        {
            Event thisEvent = null;
            if (Instance._eventDictionary.TryGetValue(eventName, out thisEvent))
            {
                thisEvent.AddListener(listener);
            }
            else
            {
                thisEvent = new Event();
                thisEvent.AddListener(listener);
                Instance._eventDictionary.Add(eventName, thisEvent);
            }
        }

        public static void StopListening(string eventName, UnityAction<System.Object> listener)
        {
            if (Instance == null) return;
            Event thisEvent = null;
            if (Instance._eventDictionary.TryGetValue(eventName, out thisEvent))
            {
                thisEvent.RemoveListener(listener);
            }
        }

        public static void TriggerEvent(string eventName, System.Object arg=null)
        {
            Event thisEvent = null;
            if (Instance._eventDictionary.TryGetValue(eventName, out thisEvent))
            {
                thisEvent.Invoke(arg);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show the part of your code where you tried to use delegates?

Comment: Sorry I changed my code for use UnityEvent<T0>, I don't remember exactly what I tried but it never worked. Sorry, I have to finish my game for the end of the week and I am really late. I don't have enough time for retry to do a non-effective stuff.

Comment: Can you give us some examples for where you need a variable number of arguments? Is it safe to assume that each event you want to subscribe to has a single signature it can expect from subscribing methods?